# Not able to fopen a file. What owner should /var/www have?

Tags: php, fopen

I use Ubuntu 11.04.
My /var/www has owner and group shin (which is my name)

I used a simple fopen php

```
$myFile = "testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "Bobby Bopper\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "Tracy Tanner\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

But it gives an error of 'can't open file'.

Does it relate to the owner and group of www directory?
Should it be root? or www-data?

If owner is nothing to do, then the code give an error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please post the full php error that you get when you run your code

Comment: Oops my bad. I just noticed the die call which of course kills code execution to display the message passed to it - therefore my previous comment is invalid. @shin Have you managed to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running a Web server (like Apache), the owner of the server process must have permission to write to the file, as you are opening in `'w'` mode.  This doesn't have to be based on **ownership**; it could also be done by mode.  To learn about file modes, run: `man chmod`.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a complete path to fopen, not only a file name and assure the user which is running the php code has also write permissions (chmod to 666).

```
$myFile = "/var/www/testFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
```

Answer (score 1):

fopen returns a warning if it fails, turn on error reporting to get more details about your error.  Add the following line before your block of code.

```
error_reporting(-1);
```